# Firebase MAUs and Play Console MAUs have a difference of ~4x

Tags: google-analytics, google-play-console, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am reviewing my MAUs from both firebase app analytics and Google play console. Initially the MAUs from both the sources were very similar until May 2023, around 1.2M

After May 2023, the play console MAUs are around 1.4M where as in the firebase the MAUs are only ~400k.

I tried finding the MAUs from BQ but they collaborate with the firebase analytics MAUs. I have looked at app release and apart from a roll out of release there has been no major event in April.
The roll out was on 31st March and DAU anomaly has been detected at 7th April, MAU anomaly on 3rd May.
I have checked in the Firebase and data for that specific roll-out is available.

May you suggest some ways for investigation?

Thanks in advance for all the help